# Product of two independent random variables

Tags: statistics

I'm stuck trying to applying various theorems about products and quotients of random variables.

Consider the following:  Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables.  Let $f_{X_1}(x)=5x^4$ and $f_{X_2}(x)=3x^2$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$.  Find the PDF of $X_1X_2$.

When I was attempting to do this problem, I directly applied the theorem to get $Z=X_1X_2$ and $f(z)=\int\int\frac{1}{|x|}f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(z/x)\,dz\,dx=\int\int\frac{1}{|x|}5x^4 3\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^2\,dz\,dx.$  Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Is there a way to analytically arrive at the solution?  Visually, I think I'm drawing something wrong.

Comment: Does the 5x^4 and 3x^2 come into play?